# hashmap and retrieve data from it

Tags: java, android, xml

I've to do an action on more item of my listview so i create an HashMap with the name of selected application (in my list) and relative position.

```
public void createHashMap(String name, int mPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    mHashMap.put(name, mPosition);
    Toast.makeText(context, name+": "+mPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

in onItemClick of my activity class

```
        adapter.createHashMap(itemName, mPosition);
```

So, when i click on a row i show the toast with the correct information now i've need to retrieve the data into hashmap and i wrote this

```
public void retrieveHashMap() {
    Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = mHashMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        int value= mHashMap.get(key);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Key: "+key+" Value: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

This work but when i call retrieveHashMap method i show ONLY the last insert value. How can i show ALL the inserted value??

Comment: I guess, your toasts are being overwritten, since that is being done in a loop. Consider moving outside the loop.

Comment: @user3103764 I have updated my answer. You can check it and tell me if it can't work (maybe your should provide me your inserted data look like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your problem is that you initialize new hash map every time. That's why you got only the last value. Try this:

```
 public void createHashMap(String name, int mPosition) {
// init it only one time.
if(mHashMap  == null){
    mHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
mHashMap.put(name, mPosition);
Toast.makeText(context, name+": "+mPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

And the toast has a duration time, so you shouldn't call it many times. If you try write log, you should use logcat.

Update: another reason, maybe your data has duplicate the name value. Try to debug or write to logcat and see if you have insert many `name` data have the same value. Because the hash map is not accepted the duplicate key.
For example:

```
  mHashMap.put("test", 2);
  mHashMap.put("test", 3); // it will replace the item ["test" - 2] by ["test" - 3]. That's why you got only the last one.
```

And make sure your iterator should look like this:

```
 Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = mHashMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        int value= mHashMap.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: The problem remain.. Show always the last insert value :-(

Comment: Why do you need to show toast many times? It has the delay time is being overwritten. Use Logcat to write log and see that it can print out all the results or not. Or you you should write the result in the textview.

Answer (score 1):

Move `Toast.makeText` outside the while loop and create the message you want inside the loop using the keys you iterate over.

You also need to check if you override existing `mHashMap` in `createHashMap()`

Comment: I moved out of loop but the bug remain... i want to retrieve ALL the inserted value

Answer (score 0):

When you use this method

```
public void createHashMap(String name, int mPosition) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
mHashMap.put(name, mPosition);
Toast.makeText(context, name+": "+mPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

you have to save  hashmap or toast  instance. 
 when call

```
 mHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and call

```
Toast.makeText(context, name+": "+mPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

refreshed(create again) all data in instance.

Comment: How can i refresh data and instance??

Comment: @user3103764 seem u are a amateur java programmer. you have to know about live scope variables in java. when u call method and instance create in the method if not return instance from method, instance killed and you cant access to the instance.

Comment: Because he tell me that he got the same issue when try my way (stop create new instance everytime), so I think the problem is his key data can be duplicated, and hash map doesn't allow duplicated key.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are reseting mHashMap every time the method createHashMap is called:
mHashMap = **new** HashMap();

Instead, you should have this only where you declare mHashMap (as a class member) and then in createHashMap only have the "mHashMap.put(name, mPosition)" part.

Comment: I tried but the problem remain... I think the problem is that since I have a list of all installed applications on the device, when I click on for example three of them, all three must be put in the hashmap DYNAMICALLY. How could I do? for example with a for cycle but how?